# Pine Script, backtest strategy on cross product

Tags: signals, pine-script

May I ask how can I trade Gold base of the MACD Signal of Silver？

I have tried to add silver macd as and indicator, however this indicator cannot treat as a strategy of gold

Comment: Do you want one trade entity to be consumed to trigger the trade action of another trade entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `security()` function to get the MACD data from silver and run your script on gold.

Example:

```
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = request.security("TVC:SILVER", timeframe.period, ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9))
```